# Django with Postgres: Bulk insert objects ignoring conflicts, then bulk insert related objects

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have two models: Template and TemplateVersion. I want to bulk insert templates and versions so that if the template already exists, it stays as is, but only new version of this template is created.

All fields of Template is guaranteed to be together unique.

I know that Django can return pks of bulk created instances when using postgres, so I tried that:

```py
created_templates = Template.objects.bulk_create(templates_to_create, ignore_conflicts=True)
# ... here goes the code to create version objects with pks from `created_templates`
TemplateVersion.objects.bulk_create(versions_to_create)
```

Surpisingly, returning pk's don't work together with `ignore_conflicts` so I don't get pk's in `created_templates`.

So my question is: is it possible to have N templates and M versions created in less queries than N+1 (using loop to manually get_or_create templates and get their pk's) using Django ORM?